# Updating profiles with the LinkedIn REST API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Is it possible to update a profile's Education, Specialities and/or Experience via the LinkedIn API?

I am able to make normal GET calls just fine.

I ask here because documentation on their website is not yielding any results and Stackoverflow would have more practical experience with it.

**EDIT: Further searching has led me to find that this is indeed not possible. I will leave this question up for others to see in case they are wondering about the same thing.**

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write data to LinkedIn profile via our API. You can only GET the profile, not POST or PUT or DELETE it.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2016?

Comment: @Alistra I believe so, unless you use some undocumented APIs.

Answer (score 2):

In the newer API's you can.
Here is the latest API link:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-edit-api

So, yes, now you can.

Comment: A standard linkedin account cannot access this link. Can you please provide further information? Maybe how to get the appropriate account permissions?

Comment: Clearly, this is limited to developers with access to the Profile Edit API, which is impossible to get. So no, you cannot.