# Access to profiles Linkedin

Tags: upload

We are preparing an alumni portal for the University of Trento where users can associate their profile Alumnus to their profile on LinkedIn.

We would like to create an automatic task so that once we have obtained the consent of the person, an update occurs automatically from your LinkedIn profile to that Alumnus.

Depending on your agreement on API, it is possible to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972291/updating-profiles-with-the-linkedin-rest-api might help!  Also have a look here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: Stack Overflow deals with programming questions. First read the API documentation and implement something yourself and then come back to ask questions if it does not work correctly.